Animation not working after exporting to Sketchfab
This is how my animation looks like in Blender:

And then this is how it looks like when I export it to Sketchfab as an FBX

Instead of a single animation it has one for every part of the robot and they are all distorted, like the one above. Additionally, this is how it looks in static pose:

For some reason my model is tiny and there is one giant cable randomly floating. I checked and the scale of all objects is set to one.
In summary, when I export my model into Sketchfab I get a distorted animation for every part of the model and the scale is way off for the model itself being too small and one of the cables being gigantic.
(Edit) Here is the armature for the legs. It has an IK constraint and the green bones are parented to the core.

In the upper part of the model, the fronts of the weapons are parented to the rear and the rear to the torso and the torso is parented to the core.

And finally, here is the rig for the cables:


Is the animation made using an armature object? Is it parent of all the mesh objects? Is there one single "root" bone at the top of the bone hierarchy with no siblings?

Analysis
Animation data
Looking at your edit, it seems that you have multiple armature objects, plus animation on the mesh objects themselves. Animation in stored on a per-object level in Blender.
I don't know if Sketchfab handles that case correctly; when you chose one animation to play, it has to actually show you multiple at once.
In addition to that, animated scaling on tends to be a tricky thing to correctly export and import.
Hierarchy
Animating without a unified parent causes transformations to be calculated independently, leading to mismatched relative positions, pivot disparities, and export misinterpretations due to inconsistent hierarchy and differing coordinate systems.
Bone Constraints
Since you animate with constraints, you probably need to manually bake your animation on the bone level before exporting, using "Visual Keying" and "Clear Constraint":

Not baking the bones with their constraints (what the visual keying does) can lead to the transform mismatches or static bones we see in your export: afaik the default exporter's baking doesn't account for constraint-induced transforms.
And since you have multiple armatures, you have to bake each of the individually. And since this is a destructive operation, you have to save your project file before baking, then bake and export, and then reopen your file to keep the clean unbaked animation for later reuse / tweaking. Which adds lots of extra steps for you.
Solution 1 - simple but not always effective
You could try to parent all the armatures and top-parent mesh objects to an empty object that will serve as root to at least have one common point of reference for all the hierarchy. That may fix the export mismatch issues without losing much of the existing animation. But will not fix the annoyance of working with different data layers and multiple bakings to do at each export.

Solution 2 - harder but pretty much guaranteed
Otherwise, the safest and most common practice is: for one asset, have one armature as parent, itself with a single "root" bone at the top of the hierarchy, and only bones and shapekey animation (not object animation). You probably won't keep your existing animation functional by doing that, but you will be sure to avoid all the issues above.
For your case, that would mean:

Go through all your armatures and make sure there are no bones with the same name across all the armatures. This is to avoid issues when joining the armatures into one.
In object mode, select all your armature objects, hit ⎈ CtrlJ to join them into one
In edit mode, add one bone named "root", at the ground center of your asset (usually the world center), and make it parent of all the other bones that have no parent. So that your bone hierarchy have one unique top-level parent.
Add the bones you need for all the objects you used to animate without bones.
Check in Pose mode if all bone constraints are functioning as expected.
Remove the animations from the mesh objects and parent them to their new bones using weights.
Redo the animation.

After that, you can bake at once the bones with the above options, export the whole thing and reopen the file.
